# ¿El metodo Collection.shuffle() sirve para desordenar solo listas?

Tags: java, java-8

He creado un conjunto:

`Set<Integer> bombo1 = new LinkedHashSet<>();`

Y quiero desordenar el conjunto. El problema es que no se como. Lo he intentado con:

`Collections.shuffle(bombo1);`

pero solo sirve para  ordenar listas de la interfaz List. A ver si pueden ayudarme. Gracias!!

Comment: te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**

Answer (score 3):

Si deseas usar `Collections.suffle` entiendo que deseas realizar esto:

> [**Collections.suffle()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) : método usado para permutar aleatoriamente la
>   lista especificada utilizando una fuente predeterminada de
>   aleatoriedad.

Para ordenar aleatoriamente un `Set`, lo puedes realizar de esta forma, puedes agregar los valores del `Set` a un `ArrayList` y de esta forma usar el método [Collections.suffle()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List))

```
    //Crea un ArrayList a partir del Set conteniendo los valores originales.
     List<Integer> shuffleList = new ArrayList<Integer>(bombo1);
     //Permuta aleatoriamente la lista.
     Collections.shuffle(shuffleList);    
     //Crea un nuevo Set en donde se almacenarán los datos ordenados aleatoriamente.
     Set<Integer> shuffledSet = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
     //Agrega los valores ordenados alatoriamente a un nuevo Set.
     shuffledSet.addAll(shuffleMe);
```

De esta forma `shuffledSet` contendrá los valores ordenados aleatoriamente.

---

Agrego un [**ejemplo online**](https://www.ideone.com/YwEhAV):

```
    // LinkedHashSet de elementos tipo Integer.
     Set<Integer> lhset = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
     // Agrega elementos.
     lhset.add(12);
     lhset.add(1);
     lhset.add(57);
     lhset.add(0);
     lhset.add(9);
     lhset.add(34);
     System.out.println("Set original: " + lhset);


     //Crea un ArrayList a partir del Set conteniendo los valores originales.
     List<Integer> shuffleMe = new ArrayList<Integer>(lhset);
     //Permuta aleatoriamente la lista.
     Collections.shuffle(shuffleMe);    
     //Crea un nuevo Set en donde se almacenarán los datos ordenados aleatoriamente.
     Set<Integer> shuffledSet = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
     //Agrega los valores ordenados alatoriamente a un nuevo Set.
     shuffledSet.addAll(shuffleMe); 

     System.out.println("Set desordenado : " +  shuffledSet);
```

Salida:

```
Set original: [12, 1, 57, 0, 9, 34]
Set desordenado : [0, 1, 34, 12, 9, 57]
```

Comment: Añado que la interfaz Set el único orden que tiene es en el que los elementos han sido insertados. La mejor manera es ésta, mezclarlos con cualquier otra colección y luego insertarlos, no hay manera mezclarlos siendo Set.